# Force Maven not to generate target/classes directory

Tags: maven, checksum

I try to use the [Checksum Maven Plugin](https://checksum-maven-plugin.nicoulaj.net/) to generate checksum files for a distribution assemled by the Assembly plugin. Unfortunately it tries also to compute the checksum for `target/classes` directory and fails of course as it is empty.

Beside a hack is there a way to suppress the creation of `target/classes` and `target/test-classes`?

The current configuration of the Checksum Maven Plugin is the following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>artifacts</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <algorithms>
            <algorithm>MD5</algorithm>
            <algorithm>SHA-1</algorithm>
            <algorithm>SHA-256</algorithm>
        </algorithms>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: what are your current plugin configuration? Could you please share the relevant pom section.

Comment: @nullpointer I added the configuration of the plugin. The artifacts I want to generate checksums for are build by the Maven Assembly Plugin.

Comment: What command are you executing and what's the error you're getting? Would be good if you could share the logs. Trying to execute with the same configs on even an empty module succeeds for me.

Comment: The artifacts which are building built by maven-assembly-plugin will get checksums during the `deploy` phase into remote repository? So maybe I mistaken something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [files](https://checksum-maven-plugin.nicoulaj.net/files-mojo.html) goal.

The example above will generate checksum for all files in directory target (represented by the property *${project.build.directory}*).

To run, use the goal **net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.5:files**

I tested with a maven project with a assembly artifact. I could reproduce the problem from your question. I also tested this solution and it worked!

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>files</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                 <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
        <algorithms>
            <algorithm>MD5</algorithm>
            <algorithm>SHA-1</algorithm>
            <algorithm>SHA-256</algorithm>
        </algorithms>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```